# Scala problem with jMock expectations and returning a value from mock

Tags: scala, jmock

**Solved. IntelliJ didn't highlight the fact that my imports were incomplete.**

Hi,

I have a simple Scala program that I'm trying to develop using jMock. Setting basic expectations works nicely but for some reason Scala does not understand my attempt to return a value from a mock object. My maven build spews out the following error

```
TestLocalCollector.scala:45: error: not found: value returnValue
one (nodeCtx).getParameter("FilenameRegex"); will( returnValue(regex))
                                                   ^
```

And the respective code snippets are

```
@Before def setUp() : Unit = { nodeCtx = context.mock(classOf[NodeContext]) }
...
// the value to be returned
val regex = ".*\\.data"
...
// setting the expectations
one (nodeCtx).getParameter("FilenameRegex"); will( returnValue(regex))
```

To me it sounds that Scala is expecting that the static jMock method `returnValue` would be a `val`? What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you leave in the comment the right syntax you ended up using? I will include it in my answer below.

Comment: Here's the relevant parts, the `returnValue` static method was not visible, thus the errors. And the `will` method just records an action on the latest mock operation, that's why it can be on the next line or after the semicolon :)

import org.jmock.Expectations
import org.jmock.Expectations._
...
context.checking( new Expectations {{
      oneOf (nodeCtx).getParameter("FilenameRegex")
      will( returnValue(".*\\.data") )
    }})

Comment: thank you. A scope issue then. With the right imports, it works better. Answer updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure about the '`;`'?

```
one (nodeCtx).getParameter("FilenameRegex") will( returnValue(regex))
```

might work better.

In [this example](http://etorreborre.blogspot.com/2008/02/better-mocks-with-jmock-and-specs.html) you see a line like:

```
  expect {
    one(blogger).todayPosts will returnValue(List(Post("...")))
  }
```

with the following comment:

> Specify what the return value should be in the same expression by defining "will" as Scala infix operator.
>   **In the Java equivalent we would have to make a separate method call (which our favorite IDE may insist on putting on the next line!)**

```
  one(blogger).todayPosts; will(returnValue(List(Post("..."))))
                         ^
                         |
                         -- semicolon only in the *Java* version
```

---

The OP explains it himself:

> the `returnValue` static method was not visible, thus the errors.
>   And the `will` method just records an action on the latest mock operation, that's why it can be on the next line or after the semicolon :)

```
import org.jmock.Expectations 
import org.jmock.Expectations._ 
... 
context.checking( 
  new Expectations {
    { oneOf (nodeCtx).getParameter("FilenameRegex") will( returnValue(".*\\.data") ) }
  }
)
```

Comment: Hmm, the semicolon was a leftover, removed it, but now I get this `error: value will is not a member of java.lang.String`

Comment: @puudeli: that is normal, `will` accepts a jMock action, like returnValue. Not a String.

Comment: the error pinpoints to the mock object: 

`one (nodeCtx).getParameter("FilenameRegex") will returnValue(regex)`

the `getParameter` method returns a String, so the scala compiler attaches `will` to the ret val